# XSD regular expression pattern: this or nothing

Tags: regex, xsd, xsd-validation

i'm trying to define an scheme rule in XSD, for which a string is 8 characters long:

```
<PostedDate>42183296</PostedDate>
```

and space-filling is also allowed:

```
<PostedDate>        </PostedDate>
```

which led me to the XSD:

```
<xs:simpleType name="DateFormat">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="8" />            //exactly 8 characters long
</xs:simpleType>
```

but the value **can** also be empty (i.e. zero characters long):

```
<PostedDate></PostedDate>
<PostedDate />
```

which led me to naively try:

```
<xs:simpleType name="DateFormat">
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="8" />            //exactly 8 characters long
      <xs:length value="0" />            //exactly 0 characters long
</xs:simpleType>
```

Which of course isn't allowed.

As is often the case in XSD, most formats cannot be represented easily with XSD, so i opted to try a regular expression rule:

```
.{8} | ""
```

which trying to convert to XSD i type:

```
<xs:simpleType name="DateFormat">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value=".{8}|''" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

But it didn't work:

```
''20101111' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '.{8}|''' for type 'DateFormat'
```

i also tried

- `<xs:pattern value="[0-9]{8}|''" />`
- `<xs:pattern value="([0-9]{8})|('')" />`
- `<xs:pattern value="(\d{8})|('')" />`

Can anyone else thing of a pattern that solves the issue matching either
 - some specific pattern
 - empty

**Bonus:** can anyone point to the place in [the XSD documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/) that says that `\d` matches digits? Or what the other special pattern codes are?

Comment: I think `\d{8}?` should work.  `?` means that whatever's before it is optional.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I may guess that patters should look like `\d{8}|` that means "eight digits or nothing", but not eight digits or two quotes. However this doesn't explain, why `20101111` is not matched. Are you sure that there are no whitespaces or other additional symbols in the element value?
`\d` is said to match digits in the section "F.1.1 Character Class Escapes"

Comment: That's the trick i would have never figured out `\d{8}|` means *"eight digits | nothing"*. Sneaky.  And you're right; i don't know why my pattern `.{8}|''` didn't match `20101111` before - it does now. Although before i was using a web-site to validate xml+xsd. Since lunchtime i wrote an xml-studio program to give more interactive feedback.

Comment: It's also important to note that a `xs:totalDigits` restriction must come **after** a `xs:pattern` restriction. Otherwise the parser internally converts the text `000001` to the single digit `1`, which then fails to validate against the pattern `(\d){6}`, since it's not 6 characters long!

Answer (score 3):

I also in the same situation like empty string is allowed otherwise it must 6 length numbers. At last I used like the following. This works for me

```
<xs:simpleType name="DateFormat">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="|[0-9]{8}" />
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```